# How can multiple computers be kept in sync using rsync *deleteriously* and *safely*?

Tags: rsync

Imagine perhaps 5 computers all trying to keep in sync a ~60 GB directory. One could be considered a central server if that matters.

I am aware of (and am using to various extents) Nextcloud, ownCloud and Dropbox). I am interested in how to use `rsync` in a deleterious and yet safe way. I know also that it could be mixed with `inotify`. Let's assume that the sync procedure of each computer happens perhaps every 10 minutes. Is the following a sane procedure to run every few minutes on each computer?

```
rsync -avz --progress --delete   www.example.org:~/rsyncbox   ~/rsyncbox
rsync -avz --progress --delete   ~/rsyncbox                   www.example.org:~/rsyncbox
```

When I think about these multiple machines running these two commands every few minutes, while themselves making changes to the sync directory, it makes me feel like I am getting into Nash equilibrium ideas. What do you think? What would be a good approach?

Comment: If you do some changes in ~/rsyncbox just before the first line run, the changes will be lost.

Comment: I don't understand the *deleteriously* in your question. Not sure what you exactly want, but if the idea is to have synced computers where anyone can work at the same time and the changes are propagated, then I am sure the approach will not work. Rather have your users connect to a server then, and have the server continuously backed up using rsync.